# How to resize filesystem for 32GB cards with Odroid-C1

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card

When installing Ubuntu on an Odroid-C1 with a 32GB micro SD card, how do you make it use the entire card?

Following the instructions on the [Odroid wiki](http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:odroid_flashing_tools), I was able to get Ubuntu-14.04 running on my Odroid-C1 fairly painlessly. I ran the "Odroid Utility" to update all packages and expand the root filesystem, but when I run `df -H`, it shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p2  4.6G  4.2G  239M  95% /
none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            439M  4.1k  439M   1% /dev
tmpfs           444M  4.1k  444M   1% /tmp
tmpfs            89M  2.8M   86M   4% /run
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            444M   78k  444M   1% /run/shm
none            105M   25k  105M   1% /run/user
/dev/mmcblk0p1  135M  7.7M  127M   6% /media/boot
```

i.e. /dev/mmcblk0p2, my root filesystem, only has 4.6G even though I'm using a 32G micro SD card. Why is this?

Comment: which OS did you use to flash the card? Windows-Mac-Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the boot partition on the micro SD card. The standard image you flash creates a fixed size partition. Current 14.04 images are around 5GB in size. I use gparted to resize the partition to occupy the entire SD card. Other options for partitioning, e.g., parted, are possible but I like the graphical interface.

To resize, make sure you CORRECTLY identify the device of the SD card. For me, this is typically /dev/sdc since I have two hard disks (devices /dev/sda, /dev/sdb respectively). THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT AS RESIZING A PARTITION ALTERS YOUR DISK STRUCTURE/GEOMETRY.

1. Insert your eMMC / SD card reader and identify your device (assumed to be /dev/sdc)
2. In gparted select the pull-down in the top right corner, select /dev/sdc from the pull down menu.
3. The second partition (/dev/sdc2) will be the root filesystem. Click on this partition from the list of partitions; Right-click. Select "Resize" and set (or drag the partition size in the top window) to occupy the entire disk.
4. Click the "check mark" to apply your resize operation.

Hope this helps,
--drew